# How to make onChange fired in Formik and re-render the other components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, formik

I am new to React, recently I am doing a webpage as follow:
I have a page with 2 form, the first one only have 1 input field, the second one is a component from another file ( it is another form ).
The problem is the initialVal.q4 doesn't update even if I change my input, I try to use onChange to trigger the change, but onChange is not working as well. I have no idea why. Also, because there is only one submit button in this page, and the button is inside the  component, I want the component can keep getting initVal updated when I change the q4 value in the first form, so the KPIForm can utilize the value of form 1 to do other processing. But I don't know how to achieve this as well.

```js
export default function KPIForm({ initValues, pageNo, setPage }) {
    const { contextValue, setProgress, updateSection, setSection } =
        useContext(SectionsContext);
    const {
        quickStart,
        rewardsCelebrations,
        strengthsOpportunities,
        visionOfSuccess,
        numbers,
    } = contextValue;
    const progress = rewardsCelebrations.progress;

    let initVal = pageNo == 2 ? initValues : initValues.q5;
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(initValues);
    }, [initValues])

    return (
        <>
            <Box>
      ........
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Box,
  Input,
  Text,
  Flex,
  Button,
  Heading,
  Grid,
  GridItem,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { Field, Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import KPIForm from '../KPIForm';
import ButtonGroup from '../ButtonGroup';

export default function Part4({ values, setPage}) {
  const initVal = {
    q4: '',
    q5: {
      a1: ['', { value: 0, unit: '%' }, { value: 0, unit: '%' }, { value: 0, unit: '%' }, { value: 0, unit: '%' }],
      a2: ['', { value: 0, unit: '($)' }, { value: 0, unit: '($)' }, { value: 0, unit: '($)' }, { value: 0, unit: '($)' }],
    }
  };
 
  if(values){
    const { q4, q5 } = values;
    console.log(q4.answers[0]);
    console.log(q5.answers);
        initVal.q4 = q4.answers[0];
        initVal.q5 = q5.answers;
    initVal.q5.a1 = q5.answers.a1;
    initVal.q5.a2 = q5.answers.a2;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Box bg={'white'} p="4">
        <Formik
          enableReinitialize
          initialValues={{q4: initVal.q4}}
        >
          {(props) => (
            <Form>
              <Heading as="h3" size={'sm'} paddingBottom="5">
                4. Of all your PERSONAL priorities, what do you want to achieve most in the next 90 days?
              </Heading>
              <Box mb={10}>
                <Field name="q4" type="text">
                  {({field, form, meta}) => (
                    <Input 
                    borderRadius={0}
                    id="q4"
                    h="50px"
                    p="1"
                    onChange={(e)=>{console.log(e.target.value)}}
                    {...field} placeholder="Please input your answer"/>
                  )}
                </Field>
              </Box>
              <br/>
              <Heading as="h3" size={'sm'} paddingBottom="5">
                5. Now think about how to measure this. What is the best result you think deserves a reward remembering, anything greater than 80% should be rewarded.
              </Heading>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
        <KPIForm initValues={initVal} pageNo={4} setPage={setPage}/>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}
```

---

in the console, I can't find any output from the console.log in the onChange()

Comment: Could you provide a working example any live editor like codesandbox?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to provide a live sample for it, but actually it will be page contain two form, on the top is an input field, under it is a KPI form, and the submit button is at the bottom.

Comment: the KPI form need to use the input from the first form, but currently, it will only read the initialVal once (when render the page), even if I change the input field, it won't get the latest value of the field, and that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at the [chakra docs on Formik](https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started/with-formik) to confirm you're following the right approach there, but without knowing more or seeing a minimal reproduction of your issue, here is a basic working solution for a Formik form that runs both Formik's `handleChange` to keep the form UI state as well as another handler that sets the value in state so we can simply pass it on as props to our other component - the `KPIForm` component in your example.

What you're doing with `initVal` in your code is a little confusing.

First, Formik's `handleChange` is intended to take care of keeping your input updated for you. You can see this in the below example.

Second, you declared `initVal` as a const so initVal.q4 is read only. If you want to keep track of the updated value, why not use React for that? You can see `useState` in the example below tracking our input value and ensuring our `OtherComponent` that needs it will always get the updated value.

Third, semantically, trying to *update* `initVal` just feels very confusing to begin with. It's only an initial value, right?

Here's a basic example as a solution:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Formik } from "formik";

const OtherComponent = ({ name }) => <div>{name}</div>;

export default function BasicExample() {
  const initName = "Jared";
  const [name, setName] = useState(initName);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My Form</h1>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ name: initName }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
        }}
      >
        {(props) => (
          <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => {
                props.handleChange(e);
                setName(e.target.value);
              }}
              onBlur={props.handleBlur}
              value={props.values.name}
              name="name"
            />
            {props.errors.name && <div id="feedback">{props.errors.name}</div>}
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Formik>
      <OtherComponent name={name} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-input-handle-change-itu032

The rest should just be a matter of implementing the chakra input component as directed, pretty sure the [examples in the docs](https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started/with-formik) should help there - have you tried something like `<Field as={Input} name="q4" onChange={...} />`?

Hope the solution helps.